# Java ServiceImpl Methods keep returning null

Tags: java, spring, service, null, autowired

I am new to using MVC and spring and have been having trouble with adding a service file. I have 3 files: Controller.java, Service.java, and ServiceImpl.java. My goal is to move all the current service logic within the exisiting Controller class to the Service level, so I know the logic within the methods is not the issue.The problem I am facing is that all of the methods I try to call from Service.java in Controller.java return null and result in null pointer errors.

I have seen many solutions to the autowired variable being null, but I'm pretty sure that is not my issue.

**Controller.java**

```
package project.controller;

import project.type.ServiceType;
import project.service.Service;

@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(final Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Object post() {

        ServiceType var1 = service.serviceMethod(true); ---> always sets var1 to null
        service.serviceMethod2(var1); ---> Throws NPE

        switch (var1) {
            case SUCCESS:
                return "Success";
            case FAILURE:
                return "Failure";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Service.java**

```
package project.service;

public interface Service{
    public ServiceType serviceMethod(boolean bool);
    public ServiceType serviceMethod2(ServiceType serviceType);
}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
package project.service.impl;

import project.type.ServiceType;
import project.service.Service;

@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

    @Override
    public ServiceType serviceMethod(boolean bool){
       if(bool){
          return ServiceType.SUCCESS;
       }
       return ServiceType.FAILURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceType serviceMethod2(ServiceType serviceType){
       *calculate*
    }
}
```

**ServiceType.java**

```
package project.type;

public enum ServiceType {
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
}
```

**ServiceConfig.java**

```
package project.config;

import Service;
import ServiceImpl;

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public Service Service() {
        return new ServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ can see that my service variable = "service" so it seems to be pulling from the correct location.

I've done my best to recreate my code in a generic way. I feel like there is some small connection missing that might be causing this issue so any thoughts on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include the actual service implementation instead of a stub. Also your code won't compile unless you have a constructor in your controller or a non-final field. So please show the actual code instead of similar code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried to update as much as possible, but cannot share the full code as it belongs to my company. The main problem I need to solve is why var1 is set to null. That method in particular is basically identical to my real code, and theoretically should always return *something*.

Comment: Change your code to use constructor injection instead of field injection, then update us.

Comment: Unless you have some crappy `@Around` or `@After` aspect that messes up your service. Your service method should also be `public` and as mentioned the `final` field in the controller won't let the code compile. At least post code that is representative, the current code really isn't.

Comment: There must be something left in the code we see. I mean, in the Controller you're calling to `service.serviceMethod();` (no parameter passed). But in your Service, this method expects one parameter `boolean bool`. So, this 2 methods **are not the same**

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ServiceType object returned from serviceMethod() is null. As you are able to call serviceMethod() using service @Autowired. Check your serviceMethod() implementation.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading code. I have updated it to better reflect my serviceMethod functionality

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, this should be a comment for improvement of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "project")
@Configuration
```

In your configuration file. As spring must know from where to pick your beans.

Along with that change visibility of your methods

```
    public ServiceType serviceMethod(boolean bool){
      if(bool){
          return ServiceType.SUCCESS;
       }
       return ServiceType.FAILURE;
    }
```

```
public ServiceType serviceMethod2(ServiceType serviceType){
       /**calculate**/  
        return ServiceType.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: The bean is being injected, the result of the method call is `null`, if we must believe the OP.